# Can't delete any fonts because of Usermode Font Driver Host

Tags: windows, fonts, process, uninstall, hosts-file

I never had this host file interrupting me when uninstalling/deleting fonts, or even noticed this host file are even running on my PC before, but it's confirmed as Microsoft's not any just 3rd party, but now it's just any font's it won't let me delete it. But when I just try to end those two process, and uninstall the font's I want, it completely freeze my PC's screen, only way to recover it is to force shutdown. I don't want to do these everytime I uninstall fonts. Someone please help

[image]

Comment: How exactly are you attempting to remove the fonts? If there is a specific error that comes up, could you please [edit] your post to include its text?

Comment: I'm just selecting a font, I mean any font, all fonts on Font's folder on Control Panel, and hitting delete. Then it says a simple error "X Font cannot be deleted because it's in use"

Comment: Does my answer to [this similar question](https://superuser.com/q/1074972/380318) work? It requires a reboot and manual deletion of the font file, but it might do the job.

Comment: Yes it does, but what I really want is for me to not do this every single time in unnatural settings Ux like regedit. I want for Windows to go back working properly, letting me delete any font's when I want to on that Font's folder

Comment: @BenN It doesn't work for me,and I'm having the same issue. Not even once. It's a font *I* created, and windows won't let me even replace it!