# Long Font dialog box in Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts

We use Windows 7 (soon Windows 10) and Office 2013.
This user reports that her Font dialog box on Word 2013 is extremely long.
Things I have tried:

1. closing word, deleting Normal.dotm file
2. Word in safe mode
3. Uninstalled Outlook and Word and restarted and installed it back
4. Replaced computer

Having done all of the above didn't help.
Has anyone faced same problem? Any help will be appreciated!!

[image: Long Font Box]

Comment: Form in your picture doesn't seem to be standard Office font settings form, more a custom form. As we don't have the source code of it we don't even have the chance to help.

Comment: When did it start happening?

Comment: How do I get the source code?
Yes, it is happening in Word 2013. You will get the same window by starting word, Home and clicking the icon besides Font.
In this case the size of the dialogbox is Looooong. Also note that I can select only one Font at a time.

Comment: It started happening on 21st of April 2019.
I compared snapshot of the font folders with my colleague who does not have this issue. ZWAdobeF.TTF was the only font that I have and my colleague does not have. Removed this font but no go.

Comment: Are there any add-ins loaded on this system? If so disable them all and then check the behavior. Since you tried Safe Mode that should have bypassed most add-in except for maybe COM Add-ins, so check if there are any of those type and disable them. You could also try repairing Office. Finally, it could be a font corruption. See this article for help: https://superuser.com/questions/1074972/cant-delete-font-files

Comment: Is your default printer driver up-to-date and/or have you tried a different printer to set as default?

Comment: Yes Karen, I set the default printer as Microsoft XPS printer, deleted normal.dotm and restarted computer and retried. Same issue :(

Comment: Hello All,
I fixed this issue by installing Service Pack 1 for Office 2013.
Somehow this was not installed and it led me to look for a solution everywhere.
but thanks all for your help!