# How to delete open font files without reboot?

Tags: windows, fonts

There are some font files that I cannot delete. These files are not installed and they are outside of C:\Windows\Fonts. I have previewed them and now I cannot delete them.

Trying to delete them will show:

> File in Use
>
> This action cannot be completed because the file is open in System
>
> Close the file and try again.

I know I can delete them after reboot, but it will cause too much trouble every time I need to delete font files.

I have opened procexp64 and have found System process and fontdrvhost.exe have opened the files.

I of course know not to kill system process, and I have tried to force close the handles, and I got access denied.

Is it possible to delete open font files without rebooting?

Comment: Close the App using the file.  Deleting the file while in use might possibly damage the app.

Comment: The Preview Pane in File Explorer will make font files behave as if they're in use if it's enabled. Check out the answers here? https://superuser.com/a/1634249/673426

Comment: Can you you rename the font file and then delete it?

Comment: @harrymc I can rename it successfully, but after renaming the file still cannot be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If just Explorer or like embedded app, you can use IObit to unlock and delete the file.

[image: IOBit unlocker]

This works without restarting - I use it here. Windows 10 and Windows 11.

Comment: I have just installed IObit Unlocker, it is free. I was skeptical at first, but it does work.

Comment: It works, but can crash the program that locks the file, which hopefully isn't a component of Windows...

Comment: Just use care using IOBit.  I have not had any issues using proper care